# EEException: Server returned HTTP code: 404 — testing app with Google App Engine and Google Earth Engine with an authenticated access

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-earth-engine

I have the this issue.

I have Google Earth Engine to grant access to my main account. I have authenticate before I run my app. However, I still got prompted to authenticate earthengine.

Here is the trace:

```
ERROR    2018-09-04 08:51:12,986 wsgi.py:263]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud- 
sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, 
in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
File "C:\Users\esther\dev\ndvi-time-series\server.py", line 90, in <module>
ee.Initialize()
File "C:\Users\esther\dev\ndvi-time-series\lib\ee\__init__.py", line 93, in Initialize
credentials = _GetPersistentCredentials()
File "C:\Users\esther\dev\ndvi-time-series\lib\ee\_helpers.py", line 40, in _GetPersistentCredentials
raise EEException('Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account '
EEException: Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by running

earthengine authenticate

in your command line, and then retry.
INFO     2018-09-04 16:51:13,023 module.py:880] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 
500 -
INFO     2018-09-04 16:51:13,325 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 12352
INFO     2018-09-04 16:51:15,380 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 3368
```

This is what I got after authentication of Earth Engine:

```
#>earthengine authenticate
Opening the following address in a web browser:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fearthengine+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdevstorage.full_control&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&client_id=517222506229-vsmmajv00ul0bs7p89v5m89qs8eb9359.apps.googleusercontent.com

Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account, and paste the generated 
code below. If the web browser does not start, please manually browse the URL 
above.

Please enter authorization code: (authorization code)

Successfully saved authorization token.
```

So, do I have to get Google Earth Engine to grant access to the service account that I am using for the app development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You need to register the service account.  See [this reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/service_account#register-the-service-account-to-use-earth-engine).